# how do I check the last time i updated the cognos transformer?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I tried updating the cube once sometime last year and I need to know the date I did that? Is it possible to see that in the status tab in Cognos 10 administration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cube is published to Cognos BI then you can easily access cube metadata using Report Expressions in Report Studio:

- Open Report Studio against your Cube Package
- Add a text item
- Set the **Source Type** to *Report Expression*
- Edit the **Report Expression** and use one of the cube report functions, dragging in the dimension as the parameter:

  `CubeDataUpdatedOn([CubeName].[DimName])`

Run the report and it will give you the date on which the source cube was updated.